# different size 2d array multiply in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, sum

I have two 2d-array and I want to multiply such as

```
val x = Array(Array(2.0, 5.0))
val y = Array(Array(1.0, -1.0), Array(-1.0, 1.0), Array(2.0, -2.0))
```

I want to get 1d-Array like

```
Array(2.0 * 1.0 + 5.0 * -1.0, 2.0 * -1.0 + 5.0 * 1.0, 2.0 * 2.0 + 5.0 * -2.0)
```

I used `x.zip(y) map (_.zipped map (_ * _)) map (_.sum)`

But I only get `Array(-3.0)`

What am I supposed to do?

Thanks for your time.

Sorry, my mean is that x array's size will always be 1 item like Array(Array(2.0, 5.0))

Comment: Will there be only 1 item in x ?

Comment: @ccheneson
If I assign x.zip(y) map (_.zipped map (_ * _)) map (_.sum) to z
val z = x.zip(y) map (_.zipped map (_ * _)) map (_.sum)
I will get z = Array[Double](-3.0)

Comment: What I mean is if `x` could be for example `Array(Array(2.0, 5.0), Array(6.0, 2.0))` or there will *always* be 1 item like `Array(Array(2.0, 5.0))` ?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What would happen if x size is different than 1? Are nested arrays always of the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the x and y defined above, the following should work.  However, if x is an Array of Arrays, then the answer would be different.

```
scala> y map {x.flatten zip _ map {case(a,b) => a*b} reduce (_+_)}
res5: Array[Double] = Array(-3.0, 3.0, -6.0)
```

Comment: The generic answer, regardless of the size of the sub arrays would be something like 


```val z = y map { y1 => x map{ _ zip y1 map { case(a,b) => a*b } reduce (_ + _ ) } }```
that you could then flatten if needed.

Comment: `reduce(_+_)` can be replaced by `sum`

Comment: Thanks for helping me